# I am trying to connect to Oracle ATP database using JDBC thin client in an spring-boot app, but getting error: Authentication lapse

Tags: java, database, oracle, spring-boot, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have setted up an Oracle cloud Autonomous transaction Processing (ATP) database, but when I am trying to connect it to my Java Spring boot application, it is throwing error:

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, Authentication lapse 0 ms."

I have correctly configured `tnsnames.ora` file and also `sqlnet.ora` file with proper location of credentials folder. But still getting above error.

My application.properties file is as below:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@sampledb_high?TNS_ADMIN=E:\\Oracle cloud POC\\Wallet_sampleDB 
spring.datasource.username=ADMIN 
spring.datasource.password=******** 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the reason, but please check what is the version of JDBC driver you are using? Try to upgrade it to the latest 18.3 version. If you need to use an older version, you have to set the Java properties prior to starting the application. Did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Download the wallet from the UI
[image: OCI Autodb management]

then unzip the wallet zip into a folder
[image: unzipped wallet]
for spring boot configuration

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ddf9jcwvp9o3z7aa_high?TNS_ADMIN=/home/mintozzy/Downloads/Wallet_DDF9JCWVP9O3Z7AA
spring.datasource.username=READONLY_USER
spring.datasource.password=qw27dLDW4uDZf9D
```

You can see running spring boot petclinic example [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/oracle-atp-ehcache-hibernate-second-level-cache) for full [properties](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/blob/master/oracle-atp-ehcache-hibernate-second-level-cache/src/main/resources/application.properties)

[here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/ozkanpakdil.github.io/issues/16#issuecomment-1268917208) you can see how to connect sql developer to cloud db.