# Connect spring boot to oracle cloud database (with url if possible)

Tags: java, spring, database, oracle, spring-boot

I'm trying to do my first backend with spring-boot. I'm using a Database on Oracle Cloud.
The thing is to connect everyone uses
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port`.
The thing is I'm completely lost in Oracle cloud dashboard and I can't find the url. I only have a wallet (which I use to connect the DB to intellij and Oracle Sql Developer).
My DB is a "always free" so maybe it doesn't have an url and can only connect with the wallet.
So do I have to connect with wallet within my spring-boot project ? How do I do that ? 
Where shall I put the wallet then ? 
Sorry I have so many questions but Oracle cloud isn't clear to me.
Thanks for the help !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73966760/175554 I manage to connect my local and put the example to github. hope it helps, and here is my notes and screen shots https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/ozkanpakdil.github.io/issues/16#issuecomment-1268917208

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is how I solved it. I added this to my pom.xml. Hope it will help

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
        <version>19.11.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>oraclepki</artifactId>
        <version>21.5.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>osdt_cert</artifactId>
        <version>21.5.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>osdt_core</artifactId>
        <version>21.5.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three options

**1. Connecting with TLS (1521 port) and no certificates:**

- Use the TLS connection URL provided by ATP. [1521 port]
- Add the recommended JARs mentioned by @SombrHack to your classpath.
- TLS doesn't need trustStore details as arguments, so avoid passing them.

> Dont pass the following JVM arguments or System.proerties

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=wallet SSO/JKS files
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password-of-your-wallet
```

**2. Connecting with TLS and a trustStore:**

- If your program requires a trustStore for internal SSL processing
- Import the necessary JKS certificates from your wallet into your trustStore
- Pass the local trustStore's password as a Java argument using

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=your-local-trust-store-password
```

**3. Alternatively: If you still want to pass trustStore details and you don't have a local trustStore defined**

- Set your wallet's JKS file as the trustStore.
- Pass the downloaded wallet's password as the trustStore password using:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/to/wallet/JKS file
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password-of-your-wallet
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you provision autonomous database, a.k.a ATP? You can find connect string by going to Databases services from the dashboard page.

1. Go to the Database services
2. Click Autonomous Database in the left hand menu
3. Pick your DB from the list to get to the Autonomous Database Details Page
4. Click on the **DB Connection** button marked in the red box here.

[image: DB Connection]

5. This will bring out the Connections panel on the right, where you can scroll down below the wallet section to find the connect strings.

[image: ATP Connect String]

You can copy the connect string. It should show you something like this:

```
(description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=adb.region-x-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=xxxx_abcdb123_tp.adb.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=adb.region-x-1.oraclecloud.com, OU=Oracle ADB, O=Oracle Corporation, L=Redwood City, ST=California, C=US")))
```

Now, as you can see here. Port number is **1522** and the service name is **xxxx_abcdb123_tp.adb.oracle.com**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So with these information I have tried to connect with service name in Oracle SQL Developer and I got a : _Got minus one from a read call_

I don't know what that means but I'm pretty sure it will say the same in spring boot.

Comment: You will have to connect using wallet which is the only secure way to connect ATP. See if [this](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/java/atp_jdbc_springboot/atp_springboot.html) helps. **DB_URL** should point to the local directory where wallet file was downloaded to.

Comment: Hey I'm back and I tried some things. So it seems Spring can find my wallet but... It can't connect. I got this error : `Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SSO KeyStore not available
 at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:701) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:868) ~[na:na]`
I tried different jdbc versions but still doesn't work...
thanks for your help !

Comment: Nevermind some jar were missing (strange tho) but now it seems to work fine Thanks !

Comment: Good stuff! Glad it worked out.

Comment: Hei @SombrHack. Could you please provide an example of the spring application.properties with the url property as an example? Also, where did you place the wallet zip? I'm really struggling here.

Comment: I get the same SSO KeyStore not available error now. Do you remember how you've fixed it?

Comment: @AhmadBayan I just posted an answer to my post, Hope it helps !